# How to make findpeak function detect the negative peaks not the positive ones

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am wondering how can I make `findpeak` function detect the negative peaks not the positive ones, it detects the red peaks shown in the figure below and I need to detect the blue ones .. any ideas??

Many Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do `findpeaks` to the negative of your data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned, you have to use `-data`.

Here is an example,

```
x = 0 : 1e-3 : 5*pi;
t = (0 : length(x)-1)*1e-3;
y = sin(x);
[p l] = findpeaks(y);
plot(t,y);hold on
plot(t(l),p,'ko','MarkerFaceColor','g');
[pn ln] = findpeaks(-y);
plot(t(ln),-pn,'ko','MarkerFaceColor','r');
```

gives,

[image]