# Is there an opposite version of scipy find_peaks?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking for the minimum point in a plot on Python.
Is there an opposite version of the "from scipy.signal import find_peaks"?
How would you find the x-point of the local minima of a graph on python?

Comment: use the negative version of your signal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make findpeak function detect the negative peaks not the positive ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836696/how-to-make-findpeak-function-detect-the-negative-peaks-not-the-positive-ones)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just flip the data upside down and look for the peaks.

```
scipy.signal.find_peaks(-x)
```